# When to use MLOAD, FLOAD and TPT connections in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I am just collecting thoughts from you all experts and trying to learn from you. Can you share your thoughts on when to use MLOAD, FLOAD and TPT connections in informatica.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some points.

```
MLOAD (MultiLoad): 
- Each MultiLoad import task can do multiple data insert, update, and delete functions.
- Each MultiLoad delete task can remove large numbers of rows from a single table.
- Each MultiLoad import task can have up to 100 DML steps; 
- Load data into multiple tables. 
- Works in batch/interactive mode.


FLOAD (Fastload):
- Fastload works only on empty tables(Best for truncate and load strategy).
- Works in batch/interactive mode.
```

Please add/share your thoughts.